# Flexbuilder-3 -> Flashbuilder-3 (straight rename)a  Flexbuilder -> Flashbuilder (synonym + merge)

Tags: discussion, support

**EDIT**: It was suggested I revise my question, so here goes nothing:

Is it possible to disallow a tag to be used, or heavily discourage it; but keep the original tag, and all of its posts?  ie: tags for old names of products still in use, and questions being mistagged as them by users not knowing the name.

***The History:***

To my knowledge, Adobe originally released the Adobe Flashbuilder IDE under a differnet name, "Flexbuilder".  Therefore, Adobe `Flexbuilder` is REALLY Adobe `Flashbuilder`; and Adobe `Flexbuilder-3` is REALLY Adobe `Flashbuilder-3`.  After version four they released it under the proper (new) name.  `Flex` however, is the actual SDK that the IDE favors using, whilst it still supports `Actionscript-3` only projects (as does the Flash IDE.)

Therefore, valid tag combinations are:

<kbd>flex</kbd> <kbd>flashbuilder</kbd>

<kbd>flex</kbd> <kbd>flashbuilder</kbd> <kbd>flex4.5</kbd>

An example of an invalid combination is:

<kbd>flex3</kbd> <kbd>flashbuilder</kbd> (very unlikely, so no.  (requires hacking))

<kbd>flexbuilder</kbd> <kbd>flex4</kbd> (straight out impossible.)

***Proposed Solution:***

In reply to the bottom comment by Mat... No, because Flexbuilder refers to the Adobe Flash Builder pre version 4.  So it's really a different version tag :/  Flexbuilder should be Flashbuilder-2 and Flexbuilder-3 should be Flashbuilder-3 or something.  That would streamline the tags.  (this is my proposed solution)

***My Question:***

How would we solve this?

Comment: Do you have a specific tag in mind? I can't think of an example.

Comment: Example: Flexbuilder .  Even in the tag description, it's stated that this is the "previous / past name for Adobe's Flash Builder"  Yet people (with flex4.5 tags I may add) tag things Flexbuilder or Flexbuilder-3  (which is impossible if you just tagged it flex4.5 ...)  Flex3 != Flex4.5

Comment: Wouldn't synonyms work for this?

Comment: --> See "Proposed Solution" in my OP.

Comment: Why wouldn't synonyms work? I don't see a "proposed solution" in your question.

Comment: @Mat That's rather odd.

Comment: See it now, probably caching issue. I don't see what your can't be implemented with synonyms with in your proposed solution. (Don't refer to comments in your posts without giving proper context (i.e. make your question stand alone) - comments can and will disappear at any time.)

Comment: @cbroughton It's perfectly valid to have 2 tags that seem unrelated to each other as long as they are both applicable to the question.  If a question is applicable to both Flex3 *and* Flex4.5, is there a reason it shouldn't be tagged with both?

Comment: In that case, yes.  But if they are asking about something specific to the GUI of the Flashbuilder + Flex4.5 IDE... then not so much.

Comment: Somehow I don't think the site will ever be quite that cognitive.  *"Your question appears to be specific to Flashbuilder + FLex4.5, but I see you have also tagged it 'Flex3'.  Are you sure?"*  [yes.]  *"Are you really sure?"*  [yes.] *"I am going to remove the Flex3 tag anyway as it doesn't seem appropriate.  If you feel this is in error, please flag for attention so I may explain to a moderator that you are wrong..."*  Ok, maybe not quite that far...  but I do think you're expecting just a bit too much out of the system.

Answer (score 6):

I think we have **tag synonyms** for this purpose.

**EDIT**:

That is a problem we will always have. **Unfortunately, we can't prevent people from making mistakes when tagging.** We also can't lock a tag just because it's an old technology. There's always a chance that someone hiding in a cave might be using it.

Comment: I don't think you're understanding what I'm saying.  Flexbuilder and Flashbuilder are not the same things.  Flexbuilder would really be Flashbuilder-2 and Flexbuilder-3 would be Flashbuilder-3.  It would be a straight rename more than just a synonym; and people tagging their questions with unusual version tags isn't helping. (in my comment I made an example)

Comment: @cbroughton Just because it's an unusual tag to use it doesn't mean that it wasn't what the person intended. Updated answer.

Comment: Even then, not lock; but ask them if they meant Flashbuilder ?  I've seen something of the sort when typing a tag, the only displayed tags were the related or synonymous tags; but I could still use the tag in question, was weird.

Comment: A HINT system might be interesting, but that's not what you proposed on the question.

Comment: Hmm, you have a really good point.  Perhaps you should post that as a suggested solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to blacklist a tag: that prevents the tag from being used on new questions, and forces you to remove the tag if you want to edit a question that has it. Only developers can blacklist a tag, and this is normally reserved for seriously ambiguous cases.

I don't quite understand what you want to do here, you may want to reformulate your arguments so that they're

1. all in one place in the question and not spread through multiple comments, and
2. comprehensible even by people who are not thoroughly familiar with Flash Builder, Flexbuilder and their history.